# Why do I have duplicate iPad USB network devices?

Tags: macos, network, usb

As you can see in the screenshot below, I have two network devices listed under *Internet Sharing*. Oddly enough, I do not however have two under the *Network* preference pane. Anyway, I was wondering a) why this might be, b) whether it is symptomatic of an underlying issue, c) if it can be resolved (easily).

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: show us the Network preferences

Comment: @Buscar웃 Sure. Post edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem disappeared for me upon upgrading to macOS Mojave.